# Bad performance on creating filtered pandas dataframe in a loop. Need suggestions to improve code

Tags: python, pandas, loops, refactoring, filtering

I'm working on some python code that generates dataframe suitable for futher EDA, BI and feature extraction.

I have one dataframe with following columns:

```py
  party_id client_id    date_st
0     pid1     clid1 2019-07-01
1     pid2     clid3 2019-06-15
2     pid3     clid3 2019-06-14
3     pid4     clid2 2019-07-01
4     pid5     clid2 2019-04-03
5     pid6     clid3 2019-04-03
6     pid7     clid1 2019-05-20
```

where party_id is unique, other cols are not. This means than one client can represent several different parties (even in one date). Party can be deemed as a unique deal for a particular customer.

And there is another dataframe:

```py
   fact_id client_id  fact_date  fact_sum
0     fid1     clid1 2018-06-02     24.37
1     fid2     clid1 2020-10-10      2.62
2     fid3     clid2 2016-01-04     47.52
3     fid4     clid3 2019-06-14     60.42
4     fid5     clid1 2019-04-03     32.77
5     fid6     clid2 2019-04-03     28.95
6     fid7     clid1 2019-05-20     46.49
7     fid8     clid2 2019-07-01     76.10
8     fid9     clid3 2018-12-15     85.27
9    fid10     clid1 2019-02-05     53.00
10   fid11     clid2 2017-03-18     19.25
11   fid12     clid3 2019-04-03     51.14
12   fid13     clid1 2019-02-08     56.89
13   fid14     clid2 2018-11-09     80.51
14   fid15     clid2 2019-08-15     68.08
```

where fact_id is unique, other cols are not.
This table represents previous customer purchases not directly connected to deals.

I need new dataframe constructed as follows:
for every party_id from app i need a subset of rows from facts that had place before date_st but not earlier than half a year (subject to change) ago.
In other words, I need all purchases in a window before particular deal.

I do not care if for two different parties I get two identical client_ids in one date - that's normal. Client can have two different deals in a day. And I do not need any aggregations as this dataframe will be analysed in frameworks like tsfresh.

Everyting that I've managed so far if iterating over app['party_id'] and concatenating filtered dataframes:

```py
def parse_facts(app, facts, party_id, window):
    clid = app[app['party_id']==party_id]['client_id'].values[0]
    date_st = pd.to_datetime(app[app['party_id']==party_id]['date_st'].values[0])
    temp_df = facts[
        (facts['client_id']==clid)& \
        (facts['fact_date']<date_st)& \
        (facts['fact_date']>=date_st+datetime.timedelta(days=-window))].copy()
    temp_df['party_id'] = party_id
    return temp_df


new_facts = pd.concat([parse_facts(app, facts, i, 180) for i in app['party_id'].values], ignore_index=True)
```

The resulting dataframe should look like:

```py
new_facts[['party_id', 'client_id', 'fact_date', 'fact_sum']]

   party_id client_id  fact_date  fact_sum
0      pid1     clid1 2019-04-03     32.77
1      pid1     clid1 2019-05-20     46.49
2      pid1     clid1 2019-02-05     53.00
3      pid1     clid1 2019-02-08     56.89
4      pid2     clid3 2019-06-14     60.42
5      pid2     clid3 2019-04-03     51.14
6      pid3     clid3 2019-04-03     51.14
7      pid4     clid2 2019-04-03     28.95
8      pid5     clid2 2018-11-09     80.51
9      pid6     clid3 2018-12-15     85.27
10     pid7     clid1 2019-04-03     32.77
11     pid7     clid1 2019-02-05     53.00
12     pid7     clid1 2019-02-08     56.89
```

I've managed to solve the task, but it has very poor performance on whole dataset: 50k unique parties and 11m unique facts. This leads to days of computing on my machine (96 cores, 512 gb ram) as it goes in one thread.

Can you suggest any ways of improving and refactoring code? I know loops are bad style but I can't figure out how to avoid loop in this task.

Answer (score 0):

What about merging dataframes by `client_id` first and then filtering out bad rows?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta


app['date_bg'] = app['date_st'] - timedelta(days=180)
df = pd.merge(facts, app)
df_c = (df['fact_date'] > df['date_bg']) & (df['fact_date'] < df['date_st'])
out = df[df_c][['party_id', 'client_id', 'fact_date', 'fact_sum']]
print(out.sort_values('party_id'))
```

Edit:
More memory efficient solution which came to my mind:

```
start_date = datetime(2019, 1, 1)
outs = []
for i in range(12):
    start = start_date + timedelta(days=i*31)
    start_f = start - timedelta(days=180)
    end = start_date + timedelta(days=(i+1)*31)
    
    app_sub = app[(app['date_st'] > start) & (app['date_st'] <= end)]
    facts_sub = facts[(facts['fact_date'] > start_f) & (facts['fact_date'] <= end)]
    df = pd.merge(facts_sub, app_sub)
    df_c = (df['fact_date'] > df['date_bg']) & (df['fact_date'] < df['date_st'])
    out = df[df_c][['party_id', 'client_id', 'fact_date', 'fact_sum']]
    outs.append(out)

out = pd.concat(outs)
print(out.sort_values('party_id'))
```

It divides dataframes into smaller chunks according to date, so there aren't any duplicates. Dataframes after merge will be smaller and ready to concatenate into final output.

Comment: Nice solution, tried it on slice and got what I needed. 
But it's about 35k clients (50k parties) and 11m facts. Merging app and facts would produce VERY large dataset. Any more memory efficient suggestion?